# Lifetime of a colab VM without GPU or TPU

Tags: google-colaboratory, time-limiting

I've read frequently ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082218/google-colab-about-lifetime-of-files-on-vm), [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjY9ILM4__rAhVDVc0KHdmADkEQFjABegQIDxAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbuomsoo-kim.github.io%2Fcolab%2F2020%2F03%2F15%2FGoogle-newly-launches-colab-pro.md%2F&usg=AOvVaw0ZwggOzx3rQrrvR6xQSw5r) and at tons of other places) that the VMs at google colab timeout after 12h. However, it's always about TPU and GPU accelerated VMs.

What about not-hardware-accelerated ones? Is there a time limit? Is it also 12 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted directly from the [Colaboratory FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits):

> Notebooks run by connecting to virtual machines that have maximum lifetimes that can be as much as 12 hours. Notebooks will also disconnect from VMs when left idle for too long. Maximum VM lifetime and idle timeout behavior may vary over time, or based on your usage.

In short, yes. Non-accelerated runtimes also time out after 12 hours.